# default call app for url launcher in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I use url_launcher package in my app for making a call like this:

```
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            UrlLauncher.launch('tel://${user.phoneNumber}');
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.phone,
                            color: Color(0XFF01d57f),
                          ),
                        )
```

everything works fine in the simulator, but on real app when I have another call apps like Skype, android ask for default app for calling; and if user select Skype by mistake and press "Always use this" every time Skype open for him instead of default call app how can i avoid those third party apps or just reset settings each time user enter the app ?
I also try flutter_phone_direct_caller package but same thing happened :

```
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            //set the number here
                            bool res =
                                await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(
                                    user.phoneNumber);
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.phone,
                            color: Color(0XFF01d57f),
                          ),
                        )
```